# Class of Users in C#

Tags: c#, class, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pages using Xamarin.Forms that allows the user to provide their data. The first form requires the user to input a username and password. The other page is for inputting their first and second names, address, email, ect.

How can I add the additional user information from the second page based on this implementation?

User class:

```
public class User
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public User() { }
        public User(string Username, string Password)
        {
            this.Username = Username;
            this.Password = Password;

        }
        public User(string Firstname, string Surname, string Email, string Address, string Phone)
        {
            this.Firstname = Firstname;
            this.Surname = Surname;
            this.Email = Email;
            this.Address = Address;
            this.Phone = Phone;
        }
```

This function within the Account creation page is called when "Create" button is pressed:

```
async void SignUserIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            User user = new User(entry_user.Text, entry_pass.Text);

             App.IsUserLoggedIn = true;
             Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
             await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
```

Second page - as the account already exists, I cannot use the word "new". How can I overcome this?

```
public User user_details;

private async void ProceedPage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {            
  user_details.Firstname = this.entryFName.Text;
  user_details.Surname = this.entrySName.Text;
  user_details.Phone = this.entryNumber.Text;
  user_details.Email = this.entryAddress.Text;
  user_details.Address = this.entryAddress.Text;
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You dont want to create another new user on the second page, you want to *update* certain details in the class using the public properties.  Pass the user object to the second form, but that second constructor with 5 strings will never be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is, you are try to access a variable that comes from other page. There are some plenty solutions out there. So here's some. But you can find others that more suitable than this one.

**1. Static Variable From Page 1**

You can always access a `public static` variable from anywhere of your codes.
Considering you have two pages:

```
public class Page1 : ContentPage //User input page
    {
        public static User user;
        public Page1()
        {

        }

        async void Clicked()
        {
            user = new User("username input", "password input");
        }
    }
```

And page two:

```
public class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        //Here you can access the user variable
        Page1.user.Email = "Some other input";
    }
}
```

This is good enough if you are working maybe one time registration form. So when you are finish registration, then just cleared up the `user` using `user = new User()` -> create new empty instance.

**2. Passing Variable to next page**

You can pass variable via the constructor method of new `class`.
Considering you have two pages:

```
public class Page1 : ContentPage //User input page
    {
        public Page1()
        {

        }

        async void Clicked()
        {
            User user = new User("username input", "password input");
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2(user));
        }
    }
```

And page two:

```
public class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2(User user)
    {
        //Here you can access the user variable
        user.Email = "Some other input";
    }
}
```

For a better approach, if you are not working on one-time form, you can use `Models` and `ViewModels` to make your UI and data more manageable.

There are several approach for this purpose, but I just can think this one for a simple one.

Answer (score 0):

```
User user = new User(entry_user.Text, entry_pass.Text);
```

should be

```
user_details = new User(entry_user.Text, entry_pass.Text);
```

so that `user_details` is ready for `ProceedPage_Clicked`.